# Mediatek MT7630e not working on Linux 5.0.2 & 4.20

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules

Under Elementary OS Juno, I am trying to use Mediatek M7630e WiFi, which doesn't work. I know that in Fedora 29 with the officially supported Linux 4.20 it does instead, even if not perfectly - I tried it before. The output of `lshw -C network` is:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 14:dd:a9:05:d1:dc
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.132 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7204000-f7204fff memory:f7200000-f7203fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7100000-f71fffff
```

and the one of `lspci` is:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
```

I used the standard Linux kernel 4.15.0.*-generic before and Mediatek M7630e WiFi didn't work. So I used this driver https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E.

However, since a certain version of Linux, installed via `apt-get upgrade`, that driver only corrupted the kernel and thus I stopped using it.

On the driver issues page https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E/issues/90, I've got to know the driver was to be released for Linux 4.20, officially. Thus I download it - and even Linux 5.0.2, which I am using now. I compiled Linux 5.0.2 with:

```
cd ~/linux-5.0.2
cp config-4.15.0-46-generic .config # doesn't support MT7630e; the rest works fine, even Ethernet does
make menuconfig # and mark Network device support -> Wireless LAN -> Mediatek MT76x0E (PCIe) support as module (the tool suggested so)

make
sudo make modules_install
sudo make install
```

I restarted the machine and gave `lsmod | grep mt`. The output is:

```
mt76x0e                20480  0
mt76x0_common          45056  1 mt76x0e
mt76x02_lib            61440  2 mt76x0e,mt76x0_common
mt76                   49152  3 mt76x0e,mt76x02_lib,mt76x0_common
mac80211              819200  4 mt76,mt76x0e,mt76x02_lib,mt76x0_common
cfg80211              675840  2 mt76x02_lib,mac80211
```

The output of `dmesg | grep mt` is instead:

```
[    0.119358] Performance Events: PEBS fmt2+, Broadwell events, 16-deep LBR, full-width counters, Intel PMU driver.
[   15.286109] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0: ASIC revision: 76300002
[   15.286204] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for mediatek/mt7650e.bin failed with error -2
[   15.286816] mt76x0e: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -2
```

Finally, the output of `ip a` doesn't show the WiFi and it is:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:05:d1:dc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xxx.x.xxx/xx brd xxx.xxx.x.xxx scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 86082sec preferred_lft 86082sec
    inet6 xxxx:xxx:xxx:1616:c68:6e4d:dfb4:1218/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 604483sec preferred_lft 85495sec
    inet6 xxxx:xxx:xxx:xxxx:8559:3aae:e9:5bc0/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:9b1a:99a2/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If I click the network icon on the WingPanel, WiFi networks scanning is not triggered. Thus I think there is a problem, still.

I cannot understand how to fix it.

Comment: `Direct firmware load for mediatek/mt7650e.bin failed with error -2` - errno 2 means `No such file or directory`. Do you have mt7650e.bin?

Comment: You're right, `find /lib/ "mt7650e.bin"` says `find: ‘mt7650e.bin’: No such file or directory`. I had another look at `make menuconfig` but I couldn't understand how to make it build `mt7650e.bin` too

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the `mt76x0e` and `mt76xx` modules:

```
sudo modprobe mt76x0e mt76xx
```

To restart automatically the Wifi after a suspend mode, create the script `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wifi-wakeup` containing:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Wake up the Wifi !

case $1/$2 in
    pre/*)
        modprobe -r mt76x0e mt76xx
        sleep 1
        ;;
    post/*)
        modprobe mt76x0e mt76xx
        ;;
esac
```

Make it executable:

`sudo chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wifi-wakeup`

Then, reboot your computer. After the next sleep, the Wifi will restart by itself!

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved and I hope this can avoid others to go crazy, like it has happened to me for days.

You need to compile the Linux kernel >= 4.20 with the current configuration (found in /boot/), enabling MT76x0e as described in the question.

Then, you need to do:

`sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/mediatek/
sudo ln -s /lib/firmware/mt7650.bin /lib/firmware/mediatek/mt7650e.bin
sudo rmmod mt76x0e
sudo modprobe mt76x0e`

Thanks to Luca for the support! :)

EDIT: As @jawker says, I also experience problems. WiFi works great, but if you suspend the machine, it stops working and you need to reboot (or use an Ethernet cable)

Answer (score 0):

I am having issues as well with MT7630E, although I have managed to get it to work with Arch running Linux 5.0.5. I am not using neurobins drivers. It's still extremely unstable, it's good for using the web, but as soon as I try a speedtest the WiFi gives out and won't come back unless doing a shutdown and then power on again, a normal reboot won't work.

`dmesg | grep mt76` after shutdown and boot:

```
[    3.626362] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0: Firmware Version: 1.0.07
[    4.591683] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0: EEPROM ver:01 fae:05
[    4.591689] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0: driver does not support HW RF ctrl
[    4.610301] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0f0: renamed from wlan0
```

`iwconfig` bit rate alternates between 72.2 and 1 Mb/s

```
wlp3s0f0  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"xxxxx"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:16   Missed beacon:0
```

Everything seems ok at this point, I can surf the web and do other non taxing stuff, but if I try a speedtest it gives out

`dmesg | grep mt76` after trying a speedtest:

```
[    3.623044] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0: ASIC revision: 76300002
[    3.626362] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0: Firmware Version: 1.0.07
[    4.591683] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0: EEPROM ver:01 fae:05
[    4.591689] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0: driver does not support HW RF ctrl
[    4.610301] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0f0: renamed from wlan0
[  561.724974] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0: TX DMA did not stop
[  579.407772] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0: TX DMA did not stop
[  610.954214] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0: TX DMA did not stop
```

`dmesg | grep mt76` after a normal reboot:

```
[    3.707099] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0: ASIC revision: 76300002
[    3.711256] mt76x0e 0000:03:00.0: Firmware Version: 1.0.07
[    3.737071] mt76x0e: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -5
```

It's like this until doing a shutdown, a reboot won't work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I think it should work also with Linux 5.0.2. I guess it all depends on the configuration to build the kernel

Comment: I have the save problem. Have you found a solution? Do you want to make this a question, as it is different to the above?

Comment: @GeorgeMoutsopoulos I haven't found a solution since then, but I have barely used that laptop with that particular wifi card. The driver is in mainline https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/mt76x0
I found some bug fixes concerning 5Ghz and hanging on suspend.

Have you tried the latest kernel release? Perhaps it is fixed

Comment: Thanks @jawker. There are bugfixes this month in mt76x0 that should be available in kernel 5.3. I will not try them. I decided to stay with kernel 4.15 and neurobin's module that has been working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had problems with Wi-Fi, Power off, and Suspend function,
in multiple distributions, for a month. 
Finally, I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/377050/325633) from "Pilot 6" which solved my Wi-Fi problems:

> A better solution is to install the driver using DKMS. 
> This way you won't need to re-install it after kernel upgrades. 
> Do it this way:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install git dkms build-essential
> git clone https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E.git
> cd MT7630E/
> sudo make dkms
> ```

I am using an Asus X750L laptop
and have Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter in the laptop with Debian 11.